# Move div in next line using css

Tags: asp.net, css

I have two div's one has textbox in it and other just plain text. This is how it looks:
[image] . I want to move text div which has language in it to the next line where arrow is showing in the pic. I searched every where cant find any solution the wordwrap is not working. Also i have to do this within css.

Here is the aspx code for both:

```
<asp:Panel ID="search" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" Wrap="False">
 <div id="txtBox">
   <asp:textbox id="box" runat="server"></asp:textbox>
   <div id="text" runat="server">Language</div>
 </div>
</asp:Panel>

css:

#search
{
    position:absolute; 
    top:100px;  
    height:50px;
    left:100px;
    width:1000px;    
}
#txtBox
{
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Your diagram is helpful, but your HTML would be MORE helpful.

Comment: Please place it in a Fiddle so we can take a look at the code: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: you are ***obviously*** using floated elements (*`float:...`*). give us the CSS so we can suggest a solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution for anyone who is stuck in same situation:

```
#text
{
  clear: left;
}
```

`clear:left` moves the text to next line to the bottom of the textbox. Then you can use `margin-left` to set the text at any position you want.

Comment: But you are misusing `float:left` in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use `float:left` in this situation.  `float:left` is for stacking `block` level HTML elements horizontally.

`block` level elements automatically stack vertically, which seems to be what you want.

However, the `<asp:TextBox>` is an `inline` level element, so you can put a `<br />` after it, or wrap it in a `<div>`.

Solution:

**HTML**

```
<asp:Panel ID="search" class="search-class" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" Wrap="False">
 <div id="txtBox">
   <asp:textbox id="box" runat="server"></asp:textbox>
   <br />
   <div id="text" runat="server">Language</div>
 </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

**OR**

```
<asp:Panel ID="search" class="search-class" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" Wrap="False">
 <div id="txtBox">
   <div>
     <asp:textbox id="box" runat="server"></asp:textbox>
   </div>
   <div id="text" runat="server">Language</div>
 </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

**CSS**

```
.search-class
{   /* Curt is right, the ID="search" is in a naming container, */
    /* so use class selector */
    position:absolute; 
    top:100px;  
    height:50px;
    left:100px;
    width:1000px;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tryed doing:
`clear:both` on the div with the language?

and maybe you should contain the textbox

```
/* Containing floats */
.contain:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}

/* IE6 */ 
* html .contain {
    height: 1%;
}

/* IE7 */
*:first-child+html .contain {
    min-height: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When ASP.NET controls are rendered to the client, they sometimes produce different IDs (unless specified otherwise in ASP.NET 4).

Looking at your code, I don't see any control with an ID of `txtBox`, so these styles aren't being applied.

When working with ASP.NET, I find its best to use classes for styling, as these will stay the same after rendering.

```
<asp:Panel ID="search" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" Wrap="False" CssClass="search">
 <div id="txtBox">
   <asp:textbox id="box" runat="server" CssClass="txtBox"></asp:textbox>
   <div id="text" runat="server">Language</div>
 </div>
</asp:Panel>

.search
{
    position:absolute; 
    top:100px;  
    height:50px;
    left:100px;
    width:1000px;    
}
.txtBox
{
    float: left;
}
```

I haven't tested this code, but you should now see these styles applying correctly, and therefore you can amend them as you wish.